# Insert custom image function

Tags: adobecreativesdk

I'm building an app to let user design business card.

Is there a way to let my user insert an image like a sticker but instead insert a custom logo image.

[something like this but a custom logo instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0qfT.png)

Thank you

edit : look like now its not possible. [link](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207914166-Getting-Additional-Content-for-the-Image-Editor)

"Note: it is not possible to create your own original Additional Content packs at this time. All Additional Content packs are created by Adobe."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confirm your update to your question, it is not possible at this time to supply your own content packs, [as noted here](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207914166-Getting-Additional-Content-for-the-Image-Editor).